# Unable to connect to the server from meteor cordova app

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-blaze, sockjs, ddp

The app is connected to 20mbps internet connection even though it’s not able to connect with the server.

Here’s is what I'm getting in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxsqa.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. Your phone is on a different network (e.g., your computer is on wifi, your phone on GPRS). Or, if you're in an office, your desktop is on LAN and your phone on Wifi, depending on how its configured this could be a problem
2. Your firewall (and/or system settings) is rejecting the connection. Check you can hit that URL from a browser (not from the app)